# Using ipyleaflet in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use tkinter in a notebook. It has two buttons, one just displays a text and the other should open a map (ipyleaflet). On clicking the button "Say hello" the output is displayed. But the same does not happen in case of "Map". Is this a limitation?

```
import tkinter as tk

from ipyleaflet import (
     Map,
     Marker,
     TileLayer, ImageOverlay,
     Polyline, Polygon, Rectangle, Circle, CircleMarker,
     GeoJSON,
     DrawControl
)

def map_print():
    m = Map(zoom=0)
    dc = DrawControl()
    def handle_draw(self, action, geo_json):
        print(action)
        print(geo_json)
    dc.on_draw(handle_draw)
    m.add_control(dc)
    return(m)

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.hello= tk.Button(self)
        self.hello["text"] = "Say Hello"
        self.hello["command"] = self.say_hello
        self.hello.pack(side="top")

        self.hey= tk.Button(self)
        self.hey["text"] = "Map"
        self.hey["command"] = self.say_map
        self.hey.pack(side="top")


        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_map(self):        
        M=map_print()
        M

    def say_hello(self):
        print("Hello :)")


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: do you get error when you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe/powershell ?

Comment: I found that [ipyleaflet](https://github.com/ellisonbg/ipyleaflet) is module for `IPython/Jupiter Notebook` (which works in browser) not for desktop application. BTW line with only `M` is useless - it is not IPython so you have to use `print(M)` to print/see it but if it is `IPython/Jupyter` module then it will not work outside web browser.